# Counting Operations - How many operators in a nested loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I am currently doing a personal project on Big O, and how we can classify different algorithms using linear equations and so on. And since for this school project I want to put a heavy emphasis on what we learnt during class to bump my mark (quadratics and so on), finding how I can use math to find the Big O might be nice.

From what I learnt, I start by counting the number of operators in our code. Then, depending on its time complexity, I would have to create an equation which satisfies our algorithm; for instance, if I had an algorithm that was O(n), my equation would be similar to y = mx+b.

That's really easy, but with quadratics or algorithms with nested loops, it's harder...
Let's say I have the following code...

```
void printAllPairs()
{
    //int n = 5; just using n to represent our array size, but for now we'll initlalize it to a value

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << i << "," << j << "\n"; 
        }
    }
}
```

I know this algorithm is O(n^2) and I also know it's bad practice to notate O(n^2) as O(n^2+an+b) or O(n) as O(mn+b), but how can I represent this algorithm with a quadratic equation (ex x^2 + ax + b or something similar)? I know for a fact that I have two constants (the two assignment operators in line 3 and 5), but would the operator found in "int j = 0" also be considered constant or not? Since this is a nested loop, j = 0 would have to be run again everytime the second loop is being run, right?

With O(n) equations, it's pretty simple since I can easily recongnize what operators are constants and coefficients, a.k.a. what operators are or not affected by n.

Any help on how I can notate the printAllPairs() algorithm as a quadratic equation? Sorry if it seem may seem easy for y'all, but a fellow high schooler needs help here.

Edit:

Comment: `printAllPairs` is `O(1)`, since `n` is always 5.

Comment: While @Ch3steR comment is clearly a joke... there is some truth to it - all such loops in real life can be considered O(1) as `int`/`long` is limited by max constant :)... More seriously it's very hard to figure out where you have problem and likely *talking* to a teacher may help more... In mean time refactor the code into loop calling function with inner loop - that should bring you to level you already understand... which may help with whatever you have trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to clear up something that may be an misunderstanding (though maybe I'm reading into your question a bit much). `O(n^2)` is not some shorthand or simplification for `O(n^2 + an + b)`. Rather, they refer to exactly the same thing. `O(n^2 + alog(n))` is also the same thing, as are infinitely many other expressions. What makes an algorithm quadratic is not that the complexity is a quadratic *polynomial*, but that the complexity eventually grows no faster than `an^2` for some specific `a`. And this is the value of big-O: we don't have to worry about all the possible contributions to complexity, but can instead focus on the general shape.

## Big-O with too many details

Okay, on to what I think is the meat of your question, which is how to be explicit about the constants. I wouldn't generally recommend doing this in practice, but technically this is the real deal.

Let's break the problem into parts and build up to the full thing. First, the simplest part of the algorithm:

```cpp
std::cout << i << "," << j << "\n";
```

This doesn't depend on `n`, to its time complexity is bounded above by some constant. Let's call that constant `a`. So our total time complexity for this statement is:

```
t0 = a
```

Cool, nice and simple.

Now let's introduce the innermost loop:

```cpp
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    std::cout << i << "," << j << "\n"; 
}
```

In terms of time complexity, this loop involves:

1. `n` repetitions of the constant `std::cout` statement we just analyzed.
2. `n` repetitions of some constant bookkeeping work (such as the increment, comparison, jump). Let's call the bookkeeping complexity `b1`.
3. Some extra constant work (such as initializing `j`). Let's call this complexity `b2`.

Altogether, our time complexity looks like this now:

```
t1 = n * (t0 + b1) + b2
   = n * (a + b1) + b2
```

This follows the general form of a linear polynomial in `n`.

Now we do the same thought process again.

1. `n` repetitions of the (linear) loop we just analyzed.
2. `n` repetitions of some constant bookkeeping work which we'll call `c1`.
3. Some extra constant work which we'll call `c2`.

So the time complexity of this loop is:

```
t2 = n * (t1 + c1) + c2
   = n * ((n * (a + b1) + b2) + c1) + c2
   = n^2 * (a + b1) + n * (b2 + c1) + c2
```

So we see that the algorithm is `O(n^2 * (a + b1) + n * (b2 + c1) + c2)`, which of course is equivalent to `O(n^2)`.

## Big-O in practice

And here we come to some advice about practical calculations of Big-O, which will save you a lot of headaches. I'm going to bring you back to "the value of big-O", which is that constants and non-dominant terms do not matter at all, **so don't even bother keeping track of them**. This alone will save you so many headaches.

Once again, let's break the problem. You'll see that the analysis looks just like the previous section, but with much reduced noise.

We start again with the single statement:

```cpp
std::cout << i << "," << j << "\n";
```

Since this doesn't depend on `n`, we call it constant. I.e., the time complexity is `O(1)`.

Now we introduce the innermost loop:

```cpp
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    std::cout << i << "," << j << "\n"; 
}
```

We have:

1. `n` repetitions of the `O(1)` statement we just analyzed.
2. `n` repetitions of some `O(1)` bookkeeping work.
3. Some extra `O(1)` work.

So this loop has time complexity `O(n * 1 + n * 1 + 1)`, which is equivalent to `O(n)`.

Now the outermost loop:

1. `n` repetitions of the `O(n)` loop we just analyzed.
2. `n` repetitions of some `O(1)` bookkeeping work.
3. Some extra `O(1)` work.

So this loop has time complexity `O(n * n + n * 1 + 1)`, which is equivalent to `O(n^2)`.